# HTTP requests from Node server vs Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, axios, mean-stack

we are a team of junior developers developing a new web application with Angular 7 using EAN (Angular Node Express) stack.

We have to hit around 20-25 REST endpoints to get data, perform some manipulations and display the data on the UI page.

How do we make those HTTP calls? Will it be more convenient to make HTTP calls from the Node/Express server (using axios), get the data, manipulate it and send it over to the Angular app. The Angular app will just have one endpoint call to make (to the Node/Express server) to all the data.

**Or**

Can I just make those 20-25 requests from Angular app and not involve Node/Express in the first place?

What makes more sense as I will be making 20-25 requests anyhow? Which approach would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions have pro and cons.
Personally, I would focus on my Angular components which are supposed to be agnostic of everything's around them.
Imagine you have 3 components which all need to perform HTTP calls to feed their datas.
In this configuration, I would recommend to let all each component perform their own calls. This way, they'll stay independants from each other.

On the other hand, if a component needs to perfom multiples calls, maybe it could be interesting to merge them into one request and let your API do the job.